# Bundler installation failing with saltstack gem state

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, salt-stack

I am trying to install bundler but It is failing due to the following error.

```
      ID: install_bundler
Function: gem.installed
    Name: bundler
  Result: False
 Comment: An exception occurred in this state: Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/state.py", line 1563, in call
              **cdata['kwargs'])
            File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/states/gem.py", line 81, in installed
              gems = __salt__['gem.list'](name, ruby, gem_bin=gem_bin, runas=user)
            File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/gem.py", line 206, in list_
              runas=runas)
            File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/gem.py", line 28, in _gem
              return __salt__['rbenv.do_with_ruby'](ruby, cmdline, runas=runas)
            File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/rbenv.py", line 369, in do_with_ruby
              return do(cmd, runas=runas)
            File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/rbenv.py", line 343, in do
              env=environ
            File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/cmdmod.py", line 1014, in run_all
              use_vt=use_vt)
            File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/cmdmod.py", line 391, in _run
              .format(cmd, kwargs, exc)
          CommandExecutionError: Unable to run command ['RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2', 'gem', 'list', 'bundler'] with the context {'with_communicate': True, 'shell': False, 'env': {'UPSTART_INSTANCE': '', 'UPSTART_JOB': 'salt-minion', 'LC_ALL': 'C', 'PATH': '/usr/local/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin', 'PWD': '/', 'TERM': 'linux'}, 'stdout': -1, 'close_fds': True, 'stdin': None, 'stderr': -1, 'cwd': '/root'}, reason: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
 Started: 10:19:55.195415
Duration: 91.662 ms
 Changes:
```

Here's my `rbenv.ssl` file

```
rbenv:
  pkg.latest:
    - refresh: True

rbenv-deps:
  pkg.installed:
    - names:
      - bash
      - git
      - openssl
      - libssl-dev
      - make
      - curl
      - autoconf
      - bison
      - build-essential
      - libssl-dev
      - libyaml-dev
      - libreadline6-dev
      - zlib1g-dev
      - libncurses5-dev

ruby-2.1.0:
  rbenv.absent:
    - require:
      - pkg: rbenv-deps

ruby-2.1.2:
  rbenv.installed:
    - default: True
    - require:
      - pkg: rbenv-deps

app-deps:
  pkg.installed:
    - names:
      - libxml2-dev # required by nokogiri
      - libxslt1-dev # required by nokogiri
      - g++ # required by eventmachine
      - libmysqlclient-dev # required by mysql
      - libexpat1-dev # required by xmlparser

install_bundler:
    gem.installed:
      - name: bundler
      - ruby: 2.1.2

/etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh:
  file:
    - managed
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 755
    - source: salt://rbenv/files/profile/rbenv.sh
    - require:
      - pkg: rbenv
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I tried installing it by a hack and it works.

```
'RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 rbenv exec gem install bundler':
  cmd.run:
    - unless: 'RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 rbenv exec gem list | grep bundler'
```

It would be great if anyone has any way clearer than running a command to install bundler using saltstack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to remove the ruby version from `gem.install` and everything worked fine.

```
install_bundler:
    gem.installed:
      - name: bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely certain what is going wrong but your install_bundler state should definitely require ruby-2.1.2.

It looks like whatever environment the state is running in does not have the `gem` command in its CLASSPATH.

Comment: It's also possible that it is just broken as mentioned [here](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/23215). You could try using [RVM](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.rvm.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the mentioned ticket (by NW0428).. I also couldn't find a better solution than this (which works really fine):

```
bundler:
  cmd.run:
    - name: RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 gem install bundler
    - unless: RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 gem list bundler -i
```

Answer (score 0):

We got this error when the state was trying to use the wrong `gem` command. There was a system-level Ubuntu Ruby package that was installed, and it was finding `/usr/bin/gem` first in the `PATH`, so the gem install was failing with `You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/[...] directory.`

Uninstalling the Ubuntu Ruby package solved it for us; then the state found the user-level `gem` command as it should have, and the gem install went to the right place.